# Adding to where condition dynamically - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I don't know if it's possible to do but I want to be able to add to the where conditions dynamically.  I think there is a way.  I want to be able to send one query instead of multiple queries to the database.

Here's the code I have so far

```
$elements = NutritionValues::where(function($query) use ($client_id, $products) {
        foreach($products as $product) {
            $query->where('client_id', '=', $client_id)
            ->where('product_id', '=', $product['product_id'])
            ->where('ingredient_name', '=', $product['element_name']);
        }

    })->get();
    return $elements;
```

Comment: This is not working for you? Any errors?

Comment: no errors but the problem is no results are given just an empty array

Comment: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object( [items:protected] => Array ( ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query looks good, but the data you are using to build it may give you an invalid result. Add this command before your query:

```
DB::listen(function($sql, $bindings, $time) { 
    var_dump($sql); 
    var_dump($bindings); 
});
```

to show in your page or

```
DB::listen(function($sql, $bindings, $time) { 
    Log::info($sql); 
    Log::info($bindings); 
});
```

to send to log.

It will display the generated query and the values (bindings) used to execute it. Analyse it and execute it in your cli, or whatever program you have to connect directly to your database server.

Comment: Just what I was looking for.  A way to see the display generated queries.  Thanks :).